# Receiving intent from Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-android-api-2

Suppose that the User is on Google Maps, taps on a place marker and currently on the place detail.

[image: Place detail]

Now I want to handle the intent that is generated by the "share" button above. My application is supposed to show this place with its name and location in its own map. However I've just realized that the generated intent only includes following:

Subject: Lombardi's Pizza
Text: http://goo.gl/maps/Ci2cb

So there is no geo information! Very disappointing.. Do you see any other way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

No. If the origin app doesn't send out those information, there's no other way to extract that.

However, you could try and use the URL and extract the location information. But, it can be tricky as well as not very useful.